Does the inclusion of the preposition at the end make the sentence incorrect?

I hope you didn't send the document in the state you got it.

I hope you didn't send the document in the state you got it in.


Since the second sentence basically says "I hope you didn't send the document in the state in which you received it," in my head, the second sentence is fine.
Is the second sentence grammatically accurate? Does it mean the same thing as the first sentence?

We should use version (1).
The in at the back of version (2) is incorrect. This version is equivalent to the third one embedded in your subsequent paragraph, which has an extra in:

*I hope you didn't send the document in the state in which you received it.

The relative pronoun which has antecedent the state and shouldn’t have another in preceding it.

I hope you didn't send the document in the state which you received it.

Omitting which gives us

I hope you didn't send the document in the state you received (or got) it.


The second sentence makes logical sense (with the first "in" marking the state of sending and the second "in" marking the state of getting). But it does not sound idiomatic to repeat "in". The first sentence sounds better.
Similarly: "Leave it at the place you found it" sounds better than "Leave it at the place you found it at."


To send a document in the state you got it.

Your sentence was not idiomatic, now it is. It needed a direct object.
verb phrase: to get (receive) a document in a state.
The repeating of in at the end is not necessary.
